# Using substr() in PHP not working on xpath result

Tags: php, xpath, substr

I'm still having fun learning xpath and PHP. I'm trying to cut a string that xpath returned using substr() but I'm having no luck with it. I created a seperate string to test if I was using substr() incorrectly. I achieved the result I wanted with the testing string but not the xpath result string.

```
$temp = $itemPrices->item(0)->nodeValue; // value = "$2.69 per bottle"
//$temp = "$2.69 per bottle"; // testing string

//var_dump($temp); // says both $temp's are strings (tested individually)

$itemPrice = substr($temp,1,4); // hoping for "2.69" (only works with second $temp)
echo $itemPrice; // nothing when using first $temp (xpath result)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does using `$temp = "" . $itemPrices->item(0)->nodeValue;` change the observations/results?

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere, because `->nodeValue` is a string property, so doing `substr()` on it should just work. Otherwise, add enough code so that it's reproducible.

Comment: Also, `substr(strtok($temp, ' '), 1)` may be better, in case you have prices like `$21.95 per bottle`.

Comment: Still echo'ing nothing. Should I try use preg_match with a suitable regex? Not too sure on how to do the regex though..

Comment: `var_dump()` shows the length of the string before it. Are the lengths the same in both cases?

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, the xpath one is much longer (42 chars). Tested the expression in a chrome extension and each result has a large amount of spaces within and around each result. I added trim() around the xpath $temp, now the string is 24 chars. I might try to remove all spaces in the $temp string when I set it.

Comment: Use `trim` to remove surrounding spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the surrounding spaces that came with every xpath result. My substr() statement cuts characters 1 to 4 out and since those characters were spaces it returned those spaces.

By changing
`$temp = $itemPrices->item(0)->nodeValue;`

to
`$temp = trim($itemPrices->item(0)->nodeValue);` the surrounding spaces were removed which then allowed my substr() statement to function the way I wanted.

Thanks everyone for helping with this!